# Access UIView's textview from other view

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiviewcontroller

Hello I have an app with 2 views.
The cybeeview and the moreview.
I use the cybeeview to do some calculations and I want to present them in the second view.
How can pass the data from cybeeviewcontroller.m to the moreviewcontroller??

Answer (score 0):

Good way would be to use delegation. You can either write your own protocol, or implement [- textViewDidEndEditing:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidEndEditing%3a) inside moreviewcontroller. You will also need to set up the delegate:

```
cybeeviewcontroller.yourTextView.delegate = moreviewcontroller;

//those controllers are instances of their respective classes
```

Nonetheless it must be said that unless it is a minor and unimportant calculation you're doing, it's fair to say that you are not doing it correctly. You should be setting your model values and pass model around. You can get more information in documentation, look for **Model-View-Controller** design pattern.

Comment: Actually I am doing calculations only in cybeeview and is button "More" which show calculation in more detail. So all I need is one way to pass the string from cybeeview to textview in moreview. What are you suggesting me?